# How can I get the device screen size in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I need to get the size of the screen ( width and height). How do I do this?
Is for a game that is being developed with libGDX.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```
int width = Gdx.app.getGraphics().getWidth();
int height = Gdx.app.getGraphics().getHeight();
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: That question is asked and answered many times before. You should search a bit before asking the question.